# Transpose PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to transpose the following PySpark dataframe?

Following is the pyspark dataframe.

```
+----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------------+--------+------+
|srab|srsbtp|avgm1|avgm2|avgm3|avgm4|avgm4|avgm6|avgm7|avgm8|avgm9|          avgm10|  avgm11|avgm12|
+----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------------+--------+------+
|2389|     D| null| null| null| null| null| null| null| null| null|            null|    null|  null|
|2389|     C| null| null| null| null| null| null| null| null| null|54674.1935483871|156820.0|  null|
+----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------------+--------+------+
```

I want to convert above dataframe into the following table

Desired Output:

```
srab    month   D        C
2389    avgm1   null    null
2389    avgm2   null    null
2389    avgm3   null    null
2389    avgm4   null    null
2389    avgm5   null    null
2389    avgm6   null    null
2389    avgm7   null    null
2389    avgm8   null    null
2389    avgm9   null    null
2389    avgm10  null    54674.19355
2389    avgm11  null    156820
2389    avgm12  null    null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark SQL, you can unpivot/pivot with `union all` and conditional aggregation:

```
select srab, month, 
    max(case when srsbtp = 'D' then avgm1 end) as d,
    max(case when srsbtp = 'C' then avgm1 end) as c
from (
    select srab, srsbtp, 'avgm1' as month, avgm1 from mytable
    union all srab, srsbtp, 'avgm2', avgm2 from mytable
    union all srab, srsbtp, 'avgm3', avgm3 from mytable
    ...
) t
gorup by srab, month
```

Answer (score 0):

First we can `stack` the `avgm` columns to rows, then we can `pivot` the `srsbtp` rows to columns.

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView('table')
col_list = ' '.join([f"'{'avgm'+str(i+1)}', {'avgm'+str(i+1)}," for i in range(12)])[:-1]
## col_list is a string
## "'avgm1', avgm1, 'avgm2', avgm2, 'avgm3', avgm3, 'avgm4', avgm4, 'avgm5', avgm5, 'avgm6', avgm6, 'avgm7', avgm7, 'avgm8', avgm8, 'avgm9', avgm9, 'avgm10', avgm10, 'avgm11', avgm11, 'avgm12', avgm12"

result = spark.sql(f"select srab, srsbtp, stack(12, {col_list}) as (month, value) from table") \
              .groupBy('srab', 'month') \
              .pivot('srsbtp') \
              .agg(F.sum('value')) \
              .orderBy('month')
result.show()
+----+------+----------------+----+
|srab| month|               C|   D|
+----+------+----------------+----+
|2389| avgm1|            null|null|
|2389|avgm10|54674.1935483871|null|
|2389|avgm11|        156820.0|null|
|2389|avgm12|            null|null|
|2389| avgm2|            null|null|
|2389| avgm3|            null|null|
|2389| avgm4|            null|null|
|2389| avgm5|            null|null|
|2389| avgm6|            null|null|
|2389| avgm7|            null|null|
|2389| avgm8|            null|null|
|2389| avgm9|            null|null|
+----+------+----------------+----+
```